# How to update disabled modules using Drush?

Tags: drush, multi-sites, updating

Is there a way to update disabled modules with `Drush`?

Currently, when I try to update a disabled module with Drush, I get this message:

> Project has no enabled extensions and can't be updated

Enabling the module is not an option as this is a live site, actually many sites. They all run off of the same Drupal code base. Some modules are used by some sites but not others (possibly not on the main site).

If Drush can't handle this, what's an easy alternative for updating modules?

Comment: About "They all run off of the same Drupal code base": please confirm if that is via a multi-site construction (if not how else)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `drush` for it. First, you have to get the list of all modules that you've, for it you use [`drush pm-list`](http://drush.ws/#pm-list) like this `drush pm-list --no-core --pipe --type="module"` you'll get a list of all modules (enabled, disabled and uninstalled).

After, when you get all list of your modules, you can use `drush dl [modules - list]` with this command `drush` gonna download and replace the existent module. Like he does with `drush up`.

The last problem is to run the `update.php`, unfortunately this one you've to do it for each website or you can easily code a small script that do it.

Comment: Wow. I never even thought of doing this but sounds like it would work.  Any caveats I should know about?

Comment: Btw, Drush has a command `updatedb (updb)` which essentially runs update.php.  You can call `drush @sites updb` to update all subsites all at once.

Comment: I know, when I said that you've to `update.php` is either by url or `drush` obviously :)

Comment: This 4-year old answer now has a better response, right here in this thread: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/177851/7009

Answer (score 15):

I use:
    `drush pm-updatecode --check-disabled`
followed by:
    `drush @sites updatedb`

The `--check-disabled` option was added 2014-11-04

Comment: This is now the correct response — love it accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

```
drush vset update_check_disabled 1 -y
```

Answer (score 6):

So, I just realized that updating disabled modules is possible through Drush provided that you've set the check box for `Check for updates of disabled modules and themes` in the settings of your **Update manager** manager module (at `admin/reports/updates/settings`).

Then it's a matter of issuing the command `drush up modulename` to update the module.